# Uploading an image to s3 using Lambda and node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My code works perfectly in my local environment, but when I upload to AWS (serverless) the image simply arrives broken in s3.

```
import multer from "multer";
import path from "path";
import crypto from "crypto";

const tmpFolder = path.resolve("/tmp");

export default {
  directory: tmpFolder,
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: tmpFolder,
    filename(request, file, callback) {
      const fileHash = crypto.randomBytes(10).toString("hex");
      const filename = `${file.originalname}`;

      return callback(null, filename);
    },
  }),
};
```

```
class S3Storage {
  private client: S3Client;

  constructor() {
    this.client = new S3Client({
      region: "us-east-1",
    });
  }

  async saveFile(filename: any): Promise<void> {
    const fileName = `public/user-profiles/${filename.originalname}`;

    const uploadParams = {
      Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: fileName,
      ACL: "public-read",
      Body: fs.createReadStream(filename.path),
      ContentType: "image/jpeg",
    };

    await this.client.send(new PutObjectCommand(uploadParams));
```

```
import uploadConfig from "../config/upload";

const routes = Router();
const upload = multer(uploadConfig);

routes.post("/upload", upload.single("image"), async (request, response) => {
  const { file } = request;
  console.log(request.files);

  const uploadImagesService = new UploadImagesService();

  await uploadImagesService.execute(file);

  return response.json({ success: true });
});

export default routes;
```

Image into S3:

[image: Image into s3]

Has anyone ever experienced this? I've tried several alternatives and none of them work, just using the local code on my computer.

Comment: How big is this image? Lambda has a payload size limit

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the multer package to handle file uploads in your Node.js application, and you are saving the uploaded files to a temporary folder using multer.diskStorage. Then, you are using the AWS SDK to upload the file to an S3 bucket.
One possible reason why the uploaded image is appearing broken in S3 is that the file is not being read correctly when passed to the PutObjectCommand. This could be due to differences in how the file is handled in your local environment versus AWS Lambda.
Here are some suggestions you can try to address this issue:

Check the value of the filename variable in the saveFile method. Ensure that the file path and name are correct and that the file exists.

Try using the fs.readFileSync method to read the file instead of fs.createReadStream. This method reads the entire file into memory, which may be necessary depending on the size of the file.

Make sure that you are setting the correct Content-Type header when uploading the file to S3. You have specified image/jpeg in your code, but this may not always be correct depending on the file type.

Check that you have the necessary permissions to upload files to the specified S3 bucket in your AWS environment.

You can also try increasing the timeout duration for your Lambda function. If the function is timing out before the file upload is complete, this could cause issues with the uploaded file.

I hope these suggestions help you to resolve the issue with the broken image in S3.